# Performance issue when duplicating an ngFor with an array of 100

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to make a "marquee", that airplane sign and or financial market that keeps moving from the right side to the left without stopping.

However, in addition to getting the information from the websocket and updating it in real time, I need to duplicate them so that the marquee slot is always full and this is making the CPU stay at 100%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="app-marquee-container">
  <div class="marquee-container">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLoadingQuoteData; else notIsLoadingQuoteData">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let data of ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']">
          <app-loading-skeleton type="TEXT" height="20px" width="140px" [isStyleInverse]="false"></app-loading-skeleton>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #notIsLoadingQuoteData>
      <ul>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let fakeData of duplicatedData">
          <li *ngFor="let data of quoteDataBySymbolSelected" (click)="openBilletBySymbol(data.symbol)">
            <span>{{ data.symbol }}</span>
            <span>{{ getMaskByPriceUnit(data.symbol, data.lastTradePrice, data.priceUnit) }}</span>
            <span [ngClass]="getPercentClassByValue(data.changePercent)">{{ (data.changePercent / 100) | percent:'1.2-2' }}</span>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
 quoteDataBySymbolSelected: IQuoteDataBySymbolSelected[] = [];
  duplicatedData: IQuoteDataBySymbolSelected[] = new Array(100);
```

Comment: Without seeing *all* of the code it is difficult to tell you why your cpu usage is spiking. I would remove code until it stops spiking to help identify what is causing it to spike. At least that way you can concentrate just on that relevant bit of code.

Comment: I can think of a couple things you can look into. First, you may want to look into using the technique where you only render elements that are visible or nearly visible. An example of this is the Material CDK virtual scroller: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview. Second, calling methods from your view can cause performance issues (e.g., `getMaskByPriceUnit` and `getPercentClassByValue`). They are called on every change detection cycle. If they do significant work, they can slow the application.

Comment: You can use profiler to see what happens

Comment: @Jack A.


I'm going to try to make the virtual scroll, but regarding the functions, I need to change the design with a certain value condition, what to do then to not lose performance in this sense?

Comment: In some cases you can compute the result when you first receive the data, and add it as a view model property. In other cases you can use a pipe to transform the data. The good thing about pipes is that they are not called unless their inputs change. Keep in mind, though, that this only makes a difference if the functions are doing a lot of work. Your problem is more likely caused by having a lot of elements on the page, and then moving them.

Comment: Can you implement a `trackByFn` for you `ngFor` loop in your `notIsLoadingQuoteData` template and see if that improves the performance?  If a `trackByFn` is not provided, `ngFor` will do the default equality check to distinguish elements of the collection from one another.  But if your elements have unique identifiers, you can tell it to do a much easier, cheaper equality check and it won't keep re-rendering the elements of the loop.  Please see: https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction